# Never skip leg day?

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, legs

Currently I am gaining strength (and muscle) with a 3-way split.

1. Back- biceps
2. Chest - triceps
3. Legs - Shoulder

This however is my concern, I am getting married in 6 months and bought a suit which has room for gaining muscle, but not too much in the upperleg area. I'd like to be more muscled when I am getting married, but due to my suit restrictions I cannot get too muscled in the upperleg area. While I don't want to have skinny legs and a muscular upper body, I don't want to buy another suit.

Currently I have just toned down the excersices I am doing for my legs to squats, lunges and an excersize for my calves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Six months is really not a long time.  You can get to [advanced level](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/SquatStandards.html) in 2-3 years (with proper programming) and spend six months just to put on 5-10kg to your lifts after that. By taking six months off, you might miss out on *maybe* 3-4 pounds of muscle gain.  Obviously you don't want to go backwards on your legs, so keep in mind the detraining rates outlined in [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16233/is-once-per-week-training-enough-for-building-muscle/16244#16244).

That said, it might be a good opportunity to work strictly on strength (myofibril hypertrophy -- see [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11531/recommended-workout-duration-vs-working-out-with-a-partner/11534#11534) if that's "Greek" to you) which won't add much mass. You'd be keeping your reps at singles, doubles, and triples.  That will set a foundation for more rapid sarcoplasmic hypertrophy once you're ready to gain mass.

Comment: Yep. Do what Olympic lifters that are sensitive to their weight class do: stay in the lower rep range, and focus on strength. Keep your calories consistent and not in surplus. Even cut down a bit and hang at a lower calorie level. And ditch the split and go with Stronglifts / Starting Strength.

Comment: @EricKaufman Agreed about the oly lifters.  Stronglifts/SS might be good depending on experience.  Since he has no restrictions on upper body *size* though (which seems to be his concern here), he could try a routine that gets him in the gym more often. 5x5 routines are sort of "prilepen's chart" with their rep schemes, instead of a bodybuilding routine which would get people in the 5x10 range.

Comment: You're probably right but unless someone is geared up or doing hypertrophy as an addition to "real" lifting it always seems the domain of weak, injured, and frustrated people. Hardly a scientific viewpoint, I know.